# Textbox validation with hebrew input

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, textbox

I'm making a contact page so user's can send message to me when they want.
I got a textbox that they can put thire name, and regular expression to check if the name is in the correct form.

```
[אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתץףןם\s\.]
```

My problem is that when I enter hebrew characters into the textbox its still don't recognize it and I get a validation error.

I tried the same regualr expression with an English unicode `[a-zA-Z]` and it work.

Do I need to add somthing to the .aspx page so it will "understand" that the input is in different language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you only allow one character with your regular expression?

Try to change it to

```
[אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתץףןם\s\.]*
```

Apart from that, I don´t think that you need to add any culture info to the page.